# Function that determines character frequency

Tags: installation, nsis

Is there an existing NSIS function/macro that can tell me the number of times a character(or string) occurs in a string?

For example:

```
${StrCount} "abba" "a" $0
# $0 will equal 2 (because the character 'a' occurs twice)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this function that supports both counting single chars or substring and case sensitive or insensitive:

```
Function StrCount 
    ;takes the following parameters by the stack:
    ; case sensitive ('s') or insensitive
    ; string to lookup
    ; string where to search

    Exch $2 ;Stack = ($2 test str)
    Exch    ;Stack = (test $2 str)
    Exch $1 ;Stack = ($1 $2 str)
    Exch    ;Stack = ($2 $1 str)
    Exch 2  ;Stack = (str $1 $2)
    Exch $0 ;Stack = ($0 $1 $2)
    Exch 2  ;Stack = ($2 $1 $0) just not to mess order
    Push $3
    Push $4
    Push $5 
    Push $6 ;Stack = ($6 $5 $4 $3 $2 $1 $0)

    StrLen $4 $1    
    StrCpy $5 0
    StrCpy $6 0

    ;now $0=str, $1=test, $2=s/i, $3=tmp str, $4=lookup len, $5=index, $6=count

    loop:
    StrCpy $3 $0 $4 $5
    StrCmp $3 "" end
    ${if} $2 == 's'
        StrCmpS $3 $1 count ignore
    ${else}
        StrCmp $3 $1 count ignore
    ${endif}
    count:
    IntOp $6 $6 + 1 ;count++
    ignore:
    IntOp $5 $5 + 1 ;index++
    goto loop
    end:

    Exch 6  ;Stack = ($0 $5 $4 $3 $2 $1 $6)
    Pop $0
    Pop $5
    Pop $4
    Pop $3
    Pop $2
    Pop $1  ;Stack = ($6)
    Exch $6 ;count is on top stack

FunctionEnd

!macro StrCount str look si
    Push ${str}
    Push ${look}
    Push ${si}
    Call StrCount
!macroend
!define StrCount "!insertmacro StrCount"
```

Call it like that:

```
${StrCount} "AbABABa" "Ba" "i" #or 's' for case sensitive
Pop $0
DetailPrint "count=$0"
```